# Compare string date(DD-MM-YYYY) with current date postgress

Tags: postgresql

My date stored in string format. I want to fetch data which is less then today date.

I tried `SELECT * FROM table WHERE upto_date < to_char(NOW(), 'DD-MM-YYYY')` but its not return correct data.

Comment: **Never**, ever store date values in `varchar` (or `text`) columns. If you have the chance, fix your broken data model **now**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE TO_DATE(upto_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') < current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Using text to store dates is a mistake:

- Can't ORDER BY it, since text is ordered alphabetically, 02-01-2000 comes after 01-02-2000
- Without ordering relationship, can't index it and search by range
- 01-02 is Jan 2 or Feb 1 depending on who you ask
- No validation, 69-74-9453 is correct text

So, if possible the application should use the correct type. If that's too much work, you can create a [GENERATED](https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-12-generated-columns.html) column set to `TO_DATE(upto_date,'DD-MM-YYYY')` and it will automatically keep and update the date in correct format and type along with the text date. So then you can index it and optimize your queries.